# Sending and analysing multiple commands with plink.exe in python

Tags: python, ssh, plink

I've been struggling to figure out how to send multiple commands with python through a plink ssh connection.
I'm aware of paramiko and other really good libraries but due to our application-based firewall, I cannot use python directly.

I need a solution where I create a connection, send a command and then analyse the data and then send another commands based on that, and so on...

I've tried subprocess but I could send one command or a bunch of commands in the same time, not one-by-one

```
import subprocess

command ='plink.exe -u user 12.17.46.06 -i key.ppk'

p = subprocess.Popen(command, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)

answer =  p.communicate('command')[0]
print(answer)
```

It works perfectly, but I don't get any answer after a second communicate.

I'd appreciate every little help.